# gdi32.dll not linked to Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, codeblocks

I can't use **GetStockObject** in my program. Apperently I'm not linked to gdi32.dll. It's in the system32 folder so I don't see why it can't access it. I'm using Code::Blocks. I know this is a stupid question but I really don't get why it's doing this. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to ensure that Windows headers are properly included. Make sure that your code file has this line at the top:

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

Second, you need to make sure that you instruct your linker to link to Gdi32.dll. The Windows SDK (which should have come with your IDE) includes LIB files to facilitate dynamically linking to the system DLLs. So check your project's properties in your IDE, and make sure that the linker is referencing `Gdi32.lib` (and `User32.lib` and `Kernel32.lib`, which should already be there).